# How do you switch from the deprecated <I18n> in react-18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I've updated `react-i18next` to the latest version and I see that `<I18n>` HOC is gone.

Before you could have something like this

```
public render() {
        return (
            <I18n>{(t) => (
            <div>
                <p>{t("translation_key_here")}</p>
            )}</I18n>
        );
    }
```

Now it says that module has no exported member i18n.

I've read the documentation but there could not find a way clear way on how to achieve the same result.
I've tried `withNamespace` but that does not solve my problem.

I have also have functions inside my components that render JSX.Elements , so passing `withNamespaces` is not possible there and {t} does not gets passed to them.

Is there a component or function similar to was `<I18n></I18n>` doing?

Answer (score 0):

In `react-i18next` v9 it's `<NamespacesConsumer>` and v10 it's `<Translation>`